# Ionic view navigation and transition issues

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

In my ionic app when I move to different views or states, I *often* have to deal with really bad transitions e.g the view "flashes" or "jerks". Sometimes it goes to the completely wrong view. It just seems like quite a mess.

Has anybody experienced something like this before? Any ideas as to why this is happening? Also worth mentioning that the testing I've done was on an iPhone 5C and 6S Plus running in the Ionic View app.

I don't know if this is related, but could some of this happen when code runs the first time a controller is initialized ? e.g. in your controller:

```
function saySomething() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}

// Gets run when controller loads
saySomething();
```

Should something like that be wrapped up in ionic.Platform.ready() ? e.g:

```
function saySomething() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}

ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
  saySomething();
});
```

Otherwise some 'glitches' might happen?

Comment: I'm having this same problem and finding solutions aren't readily available -  how did things end up for you?